# LocalStorage doesn't persist the data after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, persist

I have a problem with the getItem of my localStorage in my React Form. I put a onChange attribute:

```
<div className = 'InputForm' onChange={save_data}>
```

I found the setItem function to store the data in. Here is the function:

```
 function save_data(){

  let textarea = document.querySelectorAll("textarea")
  let input = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")
  let saved_fields = []
                                                              
 textarea.forEach(x => {

  saved_fields.push({
  key: x.className,
  value: x.value
  })
                                      
 })
                              
 input.forEach(x => {
  saved_fields.push({
  key: x.className,
  value: x.value
  })
                                    
 })
                                  
localStorage.setItem("saved_data", JSON.stringify(saved_fields))

}
```

My main problem is that I don't find a way to put the data back to the page after the page reload. I just found out how to persist all my inputs in the console:

```
 window.onload = dataLoad();
                                
 function dataLoad () {

  let show_saved_data = localStorage.getItem("saved_data");
                                  
  console.log('show_saved_data:',JSON.parse(show_saved_data));

 }
```

Can you guys help me find the retrieve/persist data function?

Edit : Here is the html of the form, i use props from another component. I don't know if this can change the function i need to use.

```
  <InputFields 
    stateKey = 'contactInfo' 
    key = {props.contactInfo.id}
    completedFields = {props.contactInfo}
    templateFields = {props.templates.contactInfo}
    onDataEntry = {props.onDataEntry}
    newField = {props.newField}
  />
```

Comment: This mistake is how you load. The correct syntax is `windows.onload = dataLoad;` // i.e. without the brackets

Comment: Which is why you should use `addEventListener` instead...

Comment: @StephenQuan is right, what you have done is made `window.onload` = the return value of `dataLoad()` which is nothing. While `window.onload = dataLoad` means calling `window.onload()` is the same as calling `dataLoad()` directly

Comment: I am not sure but I think `saved_fields = []` should be something like `saved_fields = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("saved_data")) || []` .

Answer (score 0):

Can we have your HTML form to help you? You should not identify your inputs / textareas by their className.

After that, by using ID as identifiers for your input / textarea, you just have to do it in reverse:

- Get your input/textarea list
- forEach items, set the value based on the ID

```js
function dataLoad () {
  var show_saved_data = localStorage.getItem("saved_data");
  var inputList = JSON.parse(show_saved_data);
  inputList.forEach(x => {
    document.getElementById(x.key).setAttribute('value', x.value);
  })
}
```

Giving us your complete HTML/JS will be easier to give you a complete solution.